# In Elm, how would I express verbally function type defn: `route : Url.Parser (Route -> a) a`?

Tags: routes, elm

I'm trying to understand this code from [`url-parser`](https://github.com/evancz/url-parser/tree/2.0.1):

```
route : Url.Parser (Route -> a) a 
route =
    Url.oneOf
        [ Url.map Home top
        , Url.map BlogList (s "blog" <?> stringParam "search")
        , Url.map BlogPost (s "blog" </> int)
        ]
```

Is it: "`route` is a function that takes 1) a `Parser`, 2) a function that takes a `Route` and returns an `a`, and 3) an `a`"?

This doesn't seem correct because if it's just listing the arguments, where is it expressing the return value of `route` itself?

I'm very new to elm, but what throws me off here is that the `->` is contained within the parens, and then there's no `->` at the end indicating what `route` returns.

Answer (score 1):

The easy answer is that `route` here is not really a function, but a constant: it represents a particular kind of `Parser`.

Now this, of course, raises the more difficult question of *what kind of parser* does it represent?

And that is a rather tricky one. I believe having some background on parser combinators could probably help here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser_combinator).

But either way,  it took me a while and I might still be getting it wrong.
These are the steps I went through:

1. Let's look at what you can do with a `Parser`. You can execute it using `parsePath` or `parseHash`. Each of which promising that if you provide a `Parser` of type `Parser (a->a) a` (where `a` is a generic type variable) then it will turn a `Location` into a `Maybe a`
2. Let's look at what kind of parser primitives you have. `string` for instance is a `Parser (String -> a) a`, while `int` is `Parser (Int -> a) a`.
3. Now, look at the combinators, especially `</>`, which is `Parser a b -> Parser b c -> Parser a c`. If you write `string </> int`, you will get a `Parser (String -> Int -> c) c`. This is possible, because the type variable in `string` can be substituted as `Int -> c`, so it becomes `Parser (String -> Int -> c) (Int -> c)`.
4. Based on no.3. I would conclude that a `Parser a b` represents a parser that can parse part of a complex `a` to reduce it to a simpler `b`.
5. From a package user's perspective this goes the other way around though. If you represent your routes with the data type `Route` you must define a `Parser (Route -> a) a` to be able to turn the url into your internal representation. If one of your constructors for `Route` is something like `MyTwoParamsRoute String Int`, then you will first need to define `myTwoParamsParser : Parser (String -> Int -> a) a` using some of the combinators (`</>` or `<?>`) and then use `map MyTwoParamsRoute myTwoParamsParse` to actually apply the constructor function.

So the long answer to your original question: `route : Parser (Route -> a) a` represents a parser which can parse a `Route` out of some string (typically either the hash or the path part of the url) -- while offering the possibility that once the string is reduced by whatever `Route` represents, the remainder can be further parsed by a different parser.

Answer (score 0):

Since you see just the function name before the `=` in `route =`, it means that it takes no arguments.
You can also see that in the annotation since there's no `->`.
There is one inside parenthesis.

`route` therefore, returns a `Url.Parser (Route -> a) a`.

From what I understand, it returns a type [`Parser a b`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/url-parser/2.0.1/UrlParser#Parser)
where `a` is a function `(Route -> a)` and `b` can be anything ( it's named `a` here, but it's irrelevant ).

The `->` is referring to that function that the type `Parser` "encapsulates".
I don't know how to explain it better, but take a look at the library functions. They work in a similar way
http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/url-parser/2.0.1/UrlParser

Comment: "Since you see just the function name before the = in route =, it means that it takes no arguments." This is not necessarily true! If you define a function that is composed of partially applied functions, it could still take an argument. See this example: https://ellie-app.com/43z59m2G3Fba1/0